# Mysql sub query id match to outer query

Tags: mysql, mysql-dependent-subquery

I have below query and I want to sub query id matched to the outer query and select the value for the same row as the parent query returns. Here It return more results in sub query and I use limit 1 but with this I get wrong results.

```
select 
    calldate,
    linkedid,
    src,
    case 
        when group_concat(disposition, ",") like '%ANSWERED%' then (
            select dst 
            from cdr cd 
            where 
                disposition = 'Answered' 
                and cd.linkedid = cdr.linkedid 
                and cdr.dst = cd.dst 
            limit 1
        )
        else dst 
    end as status,
    did,cnum,
    case 
        when group_concat(disposition, ",") like '%ANSWERED%' then 'ANS' 
        else 'NO Ans' 
    end as status 
from cdr  
where 
    dst in (
        select extension 
        from users 
        where name like '%ASMARA%' or name like '%aramsa%'
    ) 
    and calldate between '2019-10-31' and '2019-11-01' 
group by linkedid
```

Below is sample data

```
| linkedid          | uniqueid          | calldate            | src      | dst  | recordingfile                                                | billsec | duration |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+----------+
| 1572488580.364282 | 1572488595.364292 | 2019-10-31 10:23:15 | 96183245 | 8207 | external-8207-96183245-20191031-102315-1572488595.364292.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572489606.364367 | 1572489616.364377 | 2019-10-31 10:40:16 | 96872748 | 8207 | external-8207-96872748-20191031-104016-1572489616.364377.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572489995.364421 | 1572490004.364431 | 2019-10-31 10:46:44 | 82672286 | 8207 | external-8207-82672286-20191031-104644-1572490004.364431.wav |       0 |        9 |
| 1572490128.364453 | 1572490141.364465 | 2019-10-31 10:49:01 | 63499024 | 8207 | external-8207-63499024-20191031-104901-1572490141.364465.wav |       0 |       22 |
| 1572491448.364545 | 1572491457.364555 | 2019-10-31 11:10:57 | 96607528 | 8207 | external-8207-96607528-20191031-111057-1572491457.364555.wav |       0 |       11 |
| 1572493373.364735 | 1572493381.364745 | 2019-10-31 11:43:01 | 64969392 | 8207 | external-8207-64969392-20191031-114301-1572493381.364745.wav |       0 |        4 |
| 1572493590.364783 | 1572493600.364797 | 2019-10-31 11:46:40 | 97528558 | 8207 | external-8207-97528558-20191031-114640-1572493600.364797.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572495581.364966 | 1572495593.364976 | 2019-10-31 12:19:53 | 97461302 | 8207 | external-8207-97461302-20191031-121953-1572495593.364976.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572496788.365064 | 1572496800.365074 | 2019-10-31 12:40:00 | 98273311 | 8207 | external-8207-98273311-20191031-124000-1572496800.365074.wav |      57 |       60 |
| 1572498287.365153 | 1572498303.365164 | 2019-10-31 13:05:03 | 97676522 | 8207 | external-8207-97676522-20191031-130503-1572498303.365164.wav |     151 |      160 |
| 1572501139.365253 | 1572501148.365263 | 2019-10-31 13:52:28 | 96864516 | 8207 | external-8207-96864516-20191031-135228-1572501148.365263.wav |       0 |       28 |
| 1572502316.365345 | 1572502333.365355 | 2019-10-31 14:12:13 | 86722918 | 8207 | external-8207-86722918-20191031-141213-1572502333.365355.wav |       0 |        5 |
| 1572503327.365437 | 1572503343.365452 | 2019-10-31 14:29:03 | 96981919 | 8207 | external-8207-96981919-20191031-142903-1572503343.365452.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572504048.365515 | 1572504059.365525 | 2019-10-31 14:40:59 | 86722918 | 8207 | external-8207-86722918-20191031-144059-1572504059.365525.wav |      59 |       61 |
| 1572504878.365590 | 1572504890.365600 | 2019-10-31 14:54:50 | 96510073 | 8207 | external-8207-96510073-20191031-145450-1572504890.365600.wav |       0 |       15 |
| 1572504927.365611 | 1572504940.365623 | 2019-10-31 14:55:40 | 97200511 | 8207 | external-8207-97200511-20191031-145540-1572504940.365623.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572504927.365611 | 1572504940.365615 | 2019-10-31 14:56:05 | 97200511 | 8207 | external-8207-97200511-20191031-145540-1572504940.365615.wav |     196 |      196 |
| 1572508104.365882 | 1572508113.365892 | 2019-10-31 15:48:33 | 98763025 | 8207 | external-8207-98763025-20191031-154833-1572508113.365892.wav |      62 |       65 |
| 1572514680.366357 | 1572514699.366371 | 2019-10-31 17:38:19 | 81849860 | 8207 | external-8207-81849860-20191031-173819-1572514699.366371.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572518195.366524 | 1572518208.366534 | 2019-10-31 18:36:48 | 97633278 | 8207 | external-8207-97633278-20191031-183648-1572518208.366534.wav |     267 |      269 |
| 1572519995.366615 | 1572520009.366625 | 2019-10-31 19:06:49 | 94555481 | 8207 | external-8207-94555481-20191031-190649-1572520009.366625.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572521370.366670 | 1572521387.366680 | 2019-10-31 19:29:47 | 87526998 | 8207 | external-8207-87526998-20191031-192947-1572521387.366680.wav |       0 |       40 |
| 1572521370.366670 | 1572521432.366700 | 2019-10-31 19:30:32 | 87526998 | 8207 | external-8207-87526998-20191031-193032-1572521432.366700.wav |       0 |       19 |
| 1572528655.366787 | 1572528669.366797 | 2019-10-31 21:31:09 | 96778478 | 8207 | external-8207-96778478-20191031-213109-1572528669.366797.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572529231.366818 | 1572529245.366828 | 2019-10-31 21:40:45 | 96778478 | 8207 | external-8207-96778478-20191031-214045-1572529245.366828.wav |       0 |        4 |
| 1572488580.364282 | 1572488595.364288 | 2019-10-31 10:23:15 | 96183245 | 8208 | external-8208-96183245-20191031-102315-1572488595.364288.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572489606.364367 | 1572489616.364373 | 2019-10-31 10:40:16 | 96872748 | 8208 | external-8208-96872748-20191031-104016-1572489616.364373.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572489995.364421 | 1572490004.364427 | 2019-10-31 10:46:44 | 82672286 | 8208 | external-8208-82672286-20191031-104644-1572490004.364427.wav |       0 |        9 |
| 1572490128.364453 | 1572490141.364461 | 2019-10-31 10:49:01 | 63499024 | 8208 | external-8208-63499024-20191031-104901-1572490141.364461.wav |       0 |       22 |
| 1572491448.364545 | 1572491457.364551 | 2019-10-31 11:10:57 | 96607528 | 8208 | external-8208-96607528-20191031-111057-1572491457.364551.wav |       0 |       11 |
| 1572493373.364735 | 1572493381.364741 | 2019-10-31 11:43:01 | 64969392 | 8208 | external-8208-64969392-20191031-114301-1572493381.364741.wav |       0 |        4 |
| 1572493590.364783 | 1572493600.364793 | 2019-10-31 11:46:40 | 97528558 | 8208 | external-8208-97528558-20191031-114640-1572493600.364793.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572495581.364966 | 1572495593.364972 | 2019-10-31 12:19:53 | 97461302 | 8208 | external-8208-97461302-20191031-121953-1572495593.364972.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572496788.365064 | 1572496800.365070 | 2019-10-31 12:40:00 | 98273311 | 8208 | external-8208-98273311-20191031-124000-1572496800.365070.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572498287.365153 | 1572498303.365160 | 2019-10-31 13:05:03 | 97676522 | 8208 | external-8208-97676522-20191031-130503-1572498303.365160.wav |       0 |        8 |
| 1572501139.365253 | 1572501148.365259 | 2019-10-31 13:52:28 | 96864516 | 8208 | external-8208-96864516-20191031-135228-1572501148.365259.wav |       0 |       28 |
| 1572502316.365345 | 1572502333.365351 | 2019-10-31 14:12:13 | 86722918 | 8208 | external-8208-86722918-20191031-141213-1572502333.365351.wav |       0 |        5 |
| 1572503327.365437 | 1572503343.365448 | 2019-10-31 14:29:03 | 96981919 | 8208 | external-8208-96981919-20191031-142903-1572503343.365448.wav |     212 |      215 |
| 1572504048.365515 | 1572504059.365521 | 2019-10-31 14:40:59 | 86722918 | 8208 | external-8208-86722918-20191031-144059-1572504059.365521.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572504927.365611 | 1572504940.365619 | 2019-10-31 14:55:40 | 97200511 | 8208 | external-8208-97200511-20191031-145540-1572504940.365619.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572504878.365590 | 1572504890.365596 | 2019-10-31 14:54:50 | 96510073 | 8208 | external-8208-96510073-20191031-145450-1572504890.365596.wav |      69 |       85 |
| 1572508104.365882 | 1572508113.365888 | 2019-10-31 15:48:33 | 98763025 | 8208 | external-8208-98763025-20191031-154833-1572508113.365888.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572514680.366357 | 1572514699.366367 | 2019-10-31 17:38:19 | 81849860 | 8208 | external-8208-81849860-20191031-173819-1572514699.366367.wav |      58 |       61 |
| 1572518195.366524 | 1572518208.366530 | 2019-10-31 18:36:48 | 97633278 | 8208 | external-8208-97633278-20191031-183648-1572518208.366530.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572519995.366615 | 1572520009.366621 | 2019-10-31 19:06:49 | 94555481 | 8208 | external-8208-94555481-20191031-190649-1572520009.366621.wav |     199 |      201 |
| 1572521370.366670 | 1572521387.366676 | 2019-10-31 19:29:47 | 87526998 | 8208 | external-8208-87526998-20191031-192947-1572521387.366676.wav |       0 |       40 |
| 1572521370.366670 | 1572521432.366696 | 2019-10-31 19:30:32 | 87526998 | 8208 | external-8208-87526998-20191031-193032-1572521432.366696.wav |       0 |       19 |
| 1572528655.366787 | 1572528669.366793 | 2019-10-31 21:31:09 | 96778478 | 8208 | external-8208-96778478-20191031-213109-1572528669.366793.wav |     140 |      142 |
| 1572529231.366818 | 1572529245.366824 | 2019-10-31 21:40:45 | 96778478 | 8208 | external-8208-96778478-20191031-214045-1572529245.366824.wav |      75 |       79 |
| 1572488580.364282 | 1572488595.364284 | 2019-10-31 10:23:15 | 96183245 | 8209 | external-8209-96183245-20191031-102315-1572488595.364284.wav |       0 |        3 |
| 1572489606.364367 | 1572489616.364369 | 2019-10-31 10:40:16 | 96872748 | 8209 | external-8209-96872748-20191031-104016-1572489616.364369.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572489995.364421 | 1572490004.364423 | 2019-10-31 10:46:44 | 82672286 | 8209 | external-8209-82672286-20191031-104644-1572490004.364423.wav |       0 |        9 |
| 1572490128.364453 | 1572490141.364457 | 2019-10-31 10:49:01 | 63499024 | 8209 | external-8209-63499024-20191031-104901-1572490141.364457.wav |       0 |       22 |
| 1572491448.364545 | 1572491457.364547 | 2019-10-31 11:10:57 | 96607528 | 8209 | external-8209-96607528-20191031-111057-1572491457.364547.wav |       0 |       11 |
| 1572493373.364735 | 1572493381.364737 | 2019-10-31 11:43:01 | 64969392 | 8209 | external-8209-64969392-20191031-114301-1572493381.364737.wav |       0 |        5 |
| 1572493590.364783 | 1572493600.364789 | 2019-10-31 11:46:40 | 97528558 | 8209 | external-8209-97528558-20191031-114640-1572493600.364789.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572495581.364966 | 1572495593.364968 | 2019-10-31 12:19:53 | 97461302 | 8209 | external-8209-97461302-20191031-121953-1572495593.364968.wav |       0 |        6 |
| 1572496788.365064 | 1572496800.365066 | 2019-10-31 12:40:00 | 98273311 | 8209 | external-8209-98273311-20191031-124000-1572496800.365066.wav |       0 |        2 |
| 1572498287.365153 | 1572498303.365156 | 2019-10-31 13:05:03 | 97676522 | 8209 | external-8209-97676522-20191031-130503-1572498303.365156.wav |       0 |        8 |
| 1572501139.365253 | 1572501148.365255 | 2019-10-31 13:52:28 | 96864516 | 8209 | external-8209-96864516-20191031-135228-1572501148.365255.wav |       0 |       28 |
```

and below is the sample data. linkedid same represend same call so need to be shown in one record with disposition answered if answered in any row else not answered.

````
| calldate            | linkedid          | src      | status | did | cnum     | status |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------+--------+-----+----------+--------+
| 2019-10-31 10:23:15 | 1572488580.364282 | 96183245 | 8210   |     | 96183245 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 10:40:16 | 1572489606.364367 | 96872748 | 8210   |     | 96872748 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 10:46:44 | 1572489995.364421 | 82672286 | 8210   |     | 82672286 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 10:49:01 | 1572490128.364453 | 63499024 | 8210   |     | 63499024 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 11:10:57 | 1572491448.364545 | 96607528 | 8210   |     | 96607528 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 11:43:01 | 1572493373.364735 | 64969392 | 8210   |     | 64969392 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 11:46:40 | 1572493590.364783 | 97528558 | 8210   |     | 97528558 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 12:19:53 | 1572495581.364966 | 97461302 | 8210   |     | 97461302 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 12:40:00 | 1572496788.365064 | 98273311 | 8207   |     | 98273311 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 13:05:03 | 1572498287.365153 | 97676522 | 8207   |     | 97676522 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 13:52:28 | 1572501139.365253 | 96864516 | 8210   |     | 96864516 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 14:12:13 | 1572502316.365345 | 86722918 | 8210   |     | 86722918 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 14:29:03 | 1572503327.365437 | 96981919 | 8208   |     | 96981919 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 14:42:01 | 1572504048.365515 | 86722918 | 8207   |     | 86722918 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 14:54:50 | 1572504878.365590 | 96510073 | 8208   |     | 96510073 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 14:55:40 | 1572504927.365611 | 97200511 | 8207   |     | 97200511 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 15:48:33 | 1572508104.365882 | 98763025 | 8207   |     | 98763025 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 17:38:19 | 1572514680.366357 | 81849860 | 8208   |     | 81849860 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 18:36:48 | 1572518195.366524 | 97633278 | 8207   |     | 97633278 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 19:06:49 | 1572519995.366615 | 94555481 | 8208   |     | 94555481 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 19:29:47 | 1572521370.366670 | 87526998 | 8209   |     | 87526998 | NO Ans |
| 2019-10-31 21:31:09 | 1572528655.366787 | 96778478 | 8208   |     | 96778478 | ANS    |
| 2019-10-31 21:40:45 | 1572529231.366818 | 96778478 | 8208   |     | 96778478 | ANS    |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------+--------+-----+----------+--------+```
````

Comment: Please _format_ your SQL query by breaking it out over several lines, and adding four or more spaces to each line to make it appear as monospaced text.

Comment: You query can probably be optimized in more than one way. Would you please share sample data and expected results so we can provide a suggestion?

Comment: @GMB Sample and expected data added.